# "Can't bind to xx , since it isn't a know property" error in IDE , but code is working

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-directive, angular-library

[image]

> It's in **Visual Code** and the directive **hideFabOnscroll** is from my plugin and its working as expected . I think I'm missing something ,curious to know the it.

[Git repo of this package](https://github.com/keephacking/ionic-hide-fab-onscroll)

Thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what your question is here.

Comment: @Claies updated , is it clear enough?

Comment: It seems like you are using a directive like it's a bindable property;  you are getting the error because there isn't a property in `ion-header` to bind `scrollingHeader` to.  Does it work if you just declare it as an attribute, i.e. remove the `[ ]`?

Comment: @Claies , no it's not working. `[ ]` is needed for property binding to work right ?

Comment: yes, but there isn't a property `scrollingHeader` on the `ion-header` component.  What does the directive *do*, exactly?

Comment: @Claies , `scrollingHeader` is a directive which takes the `content`(reference of ion-content) as `input` and hides the header according to `scroll` event in `ion-content` .

Comment: so it doesn't try to pass any data into `ion-header` then.... so it's not really clear why you would be trying to use it like you are.  it doesn't sound to me like the directive is written correctly, but I don't have any code for it to evaluate.

Comment: @Claies , it's just an attribute directive dude , I need to hide `ion-header` element , that's y I added it to `ion-header`.

Comment: right, but you wrote this code like you were passing the value `'content'` **into** a property `scrollingHeader` **inside** the `ion-header` Component, but that property doesn't exist, which is why the IDE complains.  if the directive still manages to work, it's because it doesn't actually rely on that non-existent property, but that doesn't mean it's not declared wrong....

Comment: attribute directives don't normally use binding, which is why I asked if it worked if you remove the braces.  Perhaps you could describe the error you get when you don't supply the braces?

Comment: It actually seems like you are trying to bind to an `@input` alias inside the `scrollingHeader` directive, but something isn't quite right with how the IDE is interpreting that syntax.  Again, it seems like we need to see the code of the directive.

Comment: @Claies, removing braces will break the entire logic and I'm not handling that part well inside the library .  I created the library as a umd file and added it to property  `main` in it's `package.json` and I'm importing it from node_modules after installing it locally. But the IDE is not recognising this directive as a part of that module . I think Im missing something .

Comment: I tried to help clarify the problem, but without seeing code (and only seeing a screenshot), all I (and others) can do is offer guesses.  I'm not sure my comments help clarify anything at all about what might be going on.  Good luck figuring out what is wrong;  I still suspect the directive code is wrong but until I can see that code, I can't offer anything else.

Comment: @Claies , here you go https://github.com/keephacking/ionic-hide-fab-onscroll (this is a simple directive one with same error)